# Reinterpreting Quanta as Field Excitations: Is the Particle Concept Necessary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I've been exploring an interpretation of quantum mechanics where quanta are exclusively viewed as field excitations, without invoking particle-like properties. This approach treats what are traditionally referred to as 'quantum particles' purely as states of fields.

Background: I have a BSEE and am classically trained. My exploration into this area has been significantly aided by research conducted using advanced AI tools, including ChatGPT-4, which has allowed me to delve deeply into the associated physics. I've managed to describe all relevant equations within this framework, consistently avoiding references to particle characteristics like mass or speed.

Sufficiency of Field Excitations: In what scenarios, if any, might the conception of quanta solely as field excitations be insufficient to explain quantum phenomena? Are there specific experimental results or theoretical considerations that necessitate a particle-like interpretation?

Role of Particle-Like Properties: What are the theoretical or experimental justifications for introducing particle-like concepts (such as mass or velocity) in quantum descriptions? Are there instances where field states and wave propagation alone fail to account for observed behaviors?

I'm looking for insights into whether and why the particle perspective is essential in quantum theory, especially in light of experimental evidence.

Comment: I have played around with Bing's chat function and although I have found it useful; one must be extremely, I repeat, extremely careful. To me the chat bot has a strong tendency to oversimplify and jump to the conclusion it thinks the user wants. When I point out its mistakes it will apologize and sometimes correct itself; other times it apologizes and heads right back down the same erroneous path. If they could get that fixed it would be a "way cool" tool.

Comment: I pay for ChatGPT-4 and have developed methods to get reliable information for it.  It is important to understand two things. 
1. The AI will focus on recent ideas in the chat window.  It will forget ideas occurring in distant messages.  It needs a refresh of any idea on a consistent manner.
2. The AI might ask a question which a person would normally take an inference about what the AI would do with the answer.  There is never any such functionality in the current version of ChatCPT-4, to my knowledge.

Comment: I assume you down voted my post.  If so, please consider changing your vote or else please give me an up vote so that others will at least consider my simple question.  All I want is a knowledgeable feedback of my question without unnecessarily and incorrectly saying that I have not researched this.  I have, thoroughly.

Comment: experimentally particles exist without doubt in thousands of experiments done during the last 150 years. Quantum field theory is  mathematical , and it has successfully described these measurements and, important, predicted what newer experiments should find , successfully. Where there was doubt, the theory was expanded.  The mathematics of field theories in general can have many solutions which  are irrelevant to the reality of experimental physics and the particle interactions it needs to model mathematically.

Comment: I did not down vote your post, and I do believe that your questions are valid.

Comment: Short of being an expert, there is no way to know if the information generated by technology is reliable. And if one is an expert, then there would be little need to use technology in this way except perhaps to jog one's memory. However, short of being an expert, there is no way to know whether information generated by a person is reliable either; it is in both cases a matter of faith.  At the very least, human sources have passion for their subject accompanied by moral sensibility that should guide them on the path toward helping their fellows; something that LLM's cannot posses.

Comment: Thank you ana.  I am not changing any theory. For example.
Particle as a Field Excitation: The term "particle" in QFT refers to these quantized excitations of the field. An electron, for instance, is an excitation of the electron field. When we say a particle is "created," we mean that the field's state has changed in such a way that it now includes this excitation.

Vacuum State and Excitations: The vacuum state (|0⟩) is the state of the field with no excitations (no particles). When a creation operator acts on this state, it results in a state of the field with one quantum of excitation.

Comment: @Ghoster, the “in” and “out” states of the fields before and after an interaction can be stated describing one or more field excitations with well-defined frequency and energy states (and thus no need for the concept of velocities, or mass or inertial moments, which arise in the realm of the atom, which contains these field excitations in various conditions interacting exactly as waves).  Introducing particle concepts in the quantum realm only add to confusion. It adds no value that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clear to me that quanta *are* understood as field excitations and nothing else; at least within the framework of quantum field theory. The fields of quantum theory are less like waves than older versions of quantum theory in the sense that they are operator valued. One would certainly expect that a physical wave, as opposed to a mathematical abstraction, would be a mapping of space and time to the real numbers. What does it mean to say that at this particular point of space and time, the entity in question is this or that operator? The amplitudes of quantum mechanics are probability densities, something entirely different from the amplitudes of the classical wave equation that expresses physical displacement of an undulating medium, compression and rarefaction, or electromagnetic field strength.
Objects that obey the laws of quantum mechanics are not easy to understand in the sense that macroscopic objects are; there are simply no analogies that do not break down at some point. Although it is possible to try and understand everything from the point of view of waves, it also possible to do the same with the particle view. Physicists usually choose one or the other views depending on the ease with which one or the other views handles the problem at hand, hence the richness of the slit experiment over the photoelectric effect.

Comment: The probabilistic nature of QM and QFT are inherent limitations of our exact lack of ability to know details about the conditions of the waves being described. Once a measurement is made, this lack of knowledge is thereby removed, resulting in the probabilistic nature of the model transforming into a more definite certainty, the so called collapse of the wave function. In reality no collapse occurs, only the fact of gained knowledge.  Viewing quanta as waves removes all points of logical decoherences.

Comment: @Letsch. Not so. The strangeness of quantum mechanics goes deeper than that. It is not that we don't know, but rather, that we cannot know because the quantum has no *exact* condition to know in the first place. For years physicists had hoped for some hidden variable to restore realism, however, Bell's inequality made it possible to test this against experiment (see Aspect's exp.) and the results were in favor of quantum indeterminism. Nay, it is as Feynmann said: no one *understands* quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Magnus.  Thank you for your thoughts. As for Bell's Inequality, one of the foundational assumptions of Bell's theorem is invalid [measurement independence (the freedom to choose measurement settings independently of the hidden variables)], therefore the theorem's conclusions about the incompatibility of local hidden variable theories with quantum mechanics may not apply.  The assumption of measurement independence is indeed possibly untrue. It is not necessarily true. Therefor, no one should come to the conclusion that Bell's inequality proves quantum indeterminism.

Comment: Itis true, however that we cannot know what the determinates are. We can only know probabilistically until measured.

Comment: In other words, the measurement itself affects the condition of the wave.  In this sense a rock is making a measurement when light reflects from it, independent from any outside observer.

Comment: Well, in that case the rock *is* the observer. However, at any rate, you are one of those to whom non-local hidden variable theories are appealing. I wish you and your camp the best of luck with that approach; I must remain with the side that accepts non-determinism. For me, this is far more of a "live option" because the latest versions of Aspect's experiments deal with the problem of measurement independence to such a degree that the possibility of hidden variables either strains credulity or leads to overly complicated theories that seem to violate the simplicity intrinsic to good theory.

Comment: At any rate, I have enjoyed our exchange and hope that physics continues to provide you with a "few happy hours of suggestive thought".

Comment: Thank you Mr. Magnus! I will now have ChatGPT-4 instruct me on Aspect's experiments deal with the problem of measurement independence to such a degree that the possibility of hidden variables either strains credulity or leads to overly complicated theories that seem to violate the simplicity intrinsic to good theory.

Comment: I quickly see that Bell's inequality was instrumental in the understanding of the implications of the results of these experiments.  Again, Bell's Inequality made assumptions which are not necessarily true, therefore any conclusions based on Bell's Inequality should not be taken as dogma as is currently done by many.

Comment: I see it as a very first rate magic act. Confusing many on hidden truths.

Comment: Thanks Mr Magnus. I will address your questions. They they will instruct me.

Comment: The links to related questions were helpful to me as this as been discussed in detail here before.